# regex for folder names to search files with specific file extension

Tags: regex, shell

I want to search .rpm files recursively in folders starting with specific pattern. What I mean is, There are three folders namely build-a-1, build-a-2,build-b-1 having rpm files .

I want to search rpm files in folder names starting with build-a. To search rpm files recursively, i got solution from a previous question as follows.

```
find . -regex '.*\.rpm' -print0 | du --files0-from=- -a -h
```

I want to add script to search in specific patterned folders. Any help is greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First parameter in `find` is the source path (glob) so you can do:

```
find ./build-[ab]* -regex '.*\.rpm' -print0 | du --files0-from=- -a -h
```